# Need some help for growing Carolina Reaper

Tags: houseplants, peppers

I'm into hot and spicy thing, so I have targeted at this pepper. I live in Southeast Asia with tropical climate, I wonder if It is possible to plant this Carolina Reaper. If it does, how do you plant it properly?

My house has a yard enough for some gardening and the water is okay. But the soil is not that good at all, kind of dry with a lot of stone ( not really a stone at all more like a broken brick with cement ) and insect ( there are lots of fire ants ) .

Comment: They'll probably love tropical climates.

Comment: Can you tell us what is available to you for planting?  Containers or a garden? Access to water?...

Comment: @kevinsky my house have a yard enough for some gardening and the water is okie. But the soil is not that good at all, kind of dry with a lot of stone ( not really a stone at all more like a broken brick with cement ) and insect ( there are lots of fire ants )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your soil is not good and if you want the best chance of success. I would suggest purchasing some quality potting soil and growing the plant in a pot. If you are starting the seeds indoors. It will take about 8-10 weeks before the plant is strong enough to be transplanted in the pot with good soil. From personal experiences, the hotter the pepper the longer the plant takes to produce mature fruits. Carolina reaper is near the top of the Scoville list and I have seen my reapers take about 180-200 days from seed before I could harvest ripe fruits. The tropical climate should be good for your Carolina reaper plant.